# jQuery.contextMenu can't identify a SVG image in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a SVG image in my web page:

when I click on the SVG image, a popup is expected to open at the top of this SVG image. To show this popup I am using jQuery.context with the following configuration:

```
jQuery.contextMenu({
    selector: '#rule-icon-'+id, 
    trigger: 'none',
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
    
        handleRuleClick(key, grph, id, ruleName);
    },
    items: {
        // this contains the popup menu items
        }
    }
});
```

Here 'selector: '#rule-icon-'+id' defines the component on which the popup needs to be shown. '#rule-icon-'+id' is the id of the SVG image.

Now the issue is that in Safari browser the popup opens but not at the top of image but the top left corner of the browser. Seems like the selector attribute of jQuery.contextMenu is not able to identify the SVG image with the id that is passed
In Firefox and Chrome there is no problem and popup is opening at its right position, i.e. at the top of SVG image.

Does anyone of any such limitation of SVG image in Safari browser and its workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Following is the sag image configuration in web page:

Comment: Following is the sag image configuration in my web page:<image x="450.5" y="82.5" width="7" height="7" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="./images/rules_7x7.png" style="cursor: pointer;" id="rule-icon-4" tabindex="0"></image>